# Conflict state counterparts: what's a word that means to "prevent something from being created because of pre-existing object"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing an application logging subsystem (a software component) and I have to log system conflict events. The log is structured and all of its records are just bunches of key/value pairs, where keys denote a certain subject field/components, and values denote what actually happened. A conflict case is supposed to be a case when submitting a new object to the system must be rejected under certain circumstances. Let's say, if the system already has a user account with a certain email, then creating a new user account with exact email must be reject, and a single log record should be logged, for example:

- `CONFLICT___EXISTING_OBJECT_ID` = `31829`
- `CONFLICT___EXISTING_OBJECT_TYPE` = `User account`
- `CONFLICT___TYPE` = `Email conflict`

The prefix word `CONFLICT` might be omitted as it's just a grouping word (there much more keys in the subsystem). However, I'm not sure word `EXISTING` denotes *the already existing object that already has a unique email*. I was thinking of some alternatives like but I can't choose a good one:

- `CONFLICT___BLOCKING_OBJECT_ID` - blocking seems to have slightly another meaning
- `CONFLICT___OLD_OBJECT_ID` - this is even more confusing, because the existing object is not qualified as old one, and no time-related stuff is supposed to be used here
- `CONFLICT___CONFLICTING_OBJECT_ID` - from my understanding, the word *conflicting* should be applied to the object being submitted and then rejected for whatever reason, and this word should not be used for the already existing object.
- `CONFLICT___INHIBITOR_OBJECT_ID` - in some sense, it really can describe the existing object, but it's not a word to mean a "conflict".

Is there an adjective to describe an existing object that prevents a new object from being submitted (thus the latter is *conflicting* [from my understanding]) for some reasons in the context of some conflict in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the verb **obstructing**

[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/obstruct)

> to block or get in the way of something or someone, or to prevent something from happening or progressing by causing difficulties

Thus an existing object is *obstructing* a new object from going through.

---

or the verb **preclude**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/preclude)

> 1. to prevent the presence, existence, or occurrence of; make impossible

The existing object *precludes* the creation of a new one

Comment: I've never heard of _preclude_, but _obstructing_ seems to be the exact word I need. Thank you!